# Firebase Firestore realtime listener Service Unavailable Request timeout on Heroku

Tags: firebase, heroku, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore realtime listener: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#node.js
to find online users on my platform. If I test the same codes on a localhost, the realtime listener can be open and stay running for an indefinite period of time. But when I deploy the codes on heroku (this application), and run the same realtime listener. The listener returns a 503 (service unavailable) error after a minute or so. The responseText is

```
<title>Application Error</title>
<style media="screen">
html,body,iframe {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html,body {
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 0;
}
</style>


<iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
```

If I look at my application log, it shows a Heroku router error:

> 2020-12-11T14:52:25.150067+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/match?token=some token" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

This is a problem for me, since I do need the listener to run as long as possible. How do I solve this problem then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is my mistake. I left the real-time listener open without returning a response to the router. Hence the router is left open for an indefinitely long time. Heroku ends a request which does not return a response after 30s, ending with a H12 error response.

Since in my case, I need the listener to be open and listen to changes, I am using the listener to the front-end instead of the back-end. Glad that Firebase offers both front-end and back-end functionalities. Thank you Firebase.